# how to add image in header or footer

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

i have the following code in a footer of a web app.  i would like to know how could i add an image instead of text. thanks
here is my code
`

```
<footer id="page-footer" class="bg-body-light border-top">
                <div class="content py-0">
                    <div class="row font-size-sm">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-2 mb-1 mb-sm-0 text-center text-sm-right">
                            Crafted with <i class="fa fa-heart text-danger"></i> by <a class="font-w600" href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank">ORTHOLogika</a>
                     **    <img src="../assets/media/photos/logo1.png" alt="Responsive image" >**

</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-1 text-center text-sm-left">
                            <a class="font-w600" href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank">ORTHOLogika 1.0</a> &copy; <span data-toggle="year-copy"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
```

`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLorL.png)

i dont know how to import the image in the footer

Comment: I think that you should check the path of the image.

Comment: if the path is wrong, the image will not appear, but the message written within the alt attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The `<img>` tag is used to embed an image in an HTML page.

Images are not technically inserted into a web page; images are linked to web pages. The  tag creates a holding space for the referenced image.

The `<img>` tag has two required attributes:

`src` - Specifies the path to the image
`alt` - Specifies an alternate text for the image, if the image for some reason cannot be displayed

```
<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
```

Reference :
[W3schools - HTML  Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Path that you have given is must be wrong.
Here is for your reference

```
<header>
    <div id="top-header">   
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" />
        </div>      
        <!-- Navigation Menu -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- Image menu in Header to contain an Image and
        a sample text over that image -->
    <div id="header-image-menu">
    </div>
</header>

#header-image-menu{
    top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
#header-image-menu img{
    width: 100%;
    margin: none;
    padding: none;
}
#image-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 60%;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    color: #000;
    transform: translate(-30%, -30%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: How should this reference (code) help him? The way he wrote the path is correct but the problem is in the path itself.

Comment: I mean wrong folder